# optparse and strings

Tags: python, parsing, optparse

Trying to learn how to use outparse. So here is the situation, I think I got my setup correct its just how to set my options is kinda... confusing me. Basically I just want to check my filename to see if there are specific strings.

For example:

```
    python script.py -f filename.txt -a hello simple
```

I want it to return something like...

```
    Reading filename.txt....
    The word, Hello, was found at: Line 10
    The word, simple, was found at: Line 15
```

Here is what I have so far, I just don't know how to set it up correctly. Sorry for asking silly questions :P. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code thus far:

```
    from optparse import OptionParser

    def main():

        usage = "useage: %prog [options] arg1 arg2"
        parser = OptionParser(usage)

        parser.add_option_group("-a", "--all", action="store", type="string", dest="search_and", help="find ALL lines in the file for the word1 AND word2")

        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

        if len(args) != 1:
            parser.error("not enough number of arguments")

            #Not sure how to set the options...


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `OptionParser.add_option()`... `add_option_group()` isn't doing what you think it does... this is a complete example in the spirit of what you're after... note that `--all` relies on comma-separating the values... this makes it easier, instead of using space separation (which would require quoting the option values for `--all`.

Also note that you should check `options.search_and` and `options.filename` explicitly, instead of checking the length of `args`

```
from optparse import OptionParser

def main():
    usage = "useage: %prog [options]"
    parser = OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option("-a", "--all", type="string", dest="search_and", help="find ALL lines in the file for the word1 AND word2")
    parser.add_option("-f", "--file", type="string", dest="filename", help="Name of file")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if (options.search_and is None) or (options.filename is None):
        parser.error("not enough number of arguments")

    words = options.search_and.split(',')
    lines = open(options.filename).readlines()
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        for word in words:
            if word.lower() in line.lower():
                print "The word, %s, was found at: Line %s" % (word, idx + 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Using your same example, invoke the script with... `python script.py -f filename.txt -a hello,simple`

Comment: What if I wanted to add another option? like, lets say... one that will find the text1 OR text1? Do you think this is wise? if statement with options? like if (options.search_and is true): [...]? and so forth?

Comment: sounds great. I will give it a try. I will post the code afterwards! Python is pretty fun haha. Makes me search through files so quick. :D

Comment: Now that I think about it, technically, you are already doing an OR search with the existing example...

Comment: Hmmm.... sounds great, I am kinda stunned at the moment. I will post some later tonight (Pacific Time). I got into the zone of learning a new language and got kinda carried away. Just wrote my first script using getopt module, urllib, sys, and a bit of os. But I really wanna get this one working now :D

Comment: Is there a function in str. where I can search if the line begins with a whitespace or a tab? I looked through http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html but wasn't sure on some.

Comment: @inoobdotcom, assume `foo = ' dude'`... `if (foo[0] == ' ') or (foo[0] == '\t')`

Comment: Will I be able to use that with line.lower()? Like line[0].lower() or something?

Comment: correct...`line[0].lower()` would work fine... any string variable can be indexed and the result can be run through `.lower()`

Comment: That sounds great! Thanks Mike. Sorry for all these new questions, but you have been a great help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4211/discussion-between-inoobdotcom-and-mike-pennington)

Comment: Hey Mike I will post what I have on here. I have -a, -b, -c, and -f options and each one of those have 2 arguments. For instance, python myscript.py -a word1 word2, is how I will do it via commandline. Would (options, args) = parser.parse_args(['-f', filename, '-a', '-b', '-c', arg1, arg2] be something possible?